# Frequency of a word in a list

Tags: r

How do I count how many times does a word appear in R and the output is the one which appears the most?

```
a <- list(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A"))
```

the output should be "A"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you really have a list or vector, but with a vector

```
a <-c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A")
```

you can do

```
names(sort(table(a), decreasing=TRUE))[1]
```

to get the most common value

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` with the `decreasing=TRUE` flag:

```
sort(table(list(c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "A"))),decreasing=TRUE)[1]
```

Output:

```
A 
6
```